# Equivalent of phpinfo() in Node

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

What is the equivalent in **Node** of **phpinfo** to check configuration settings ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-info) to a package (nodejs-info) that provides the same type of information.

If you're looking to see what environment variables exist, you could also `console.log` them like: `console.log(process.env);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly equivalent* to `phpinfo()` but any questions you'd typically ask of phpinfo can be answered by the `process` global variable. Rastalamm's answer touches on this, but there's a ton more than just `process.env`.

Much like phpinfo, `console.log(process)` will tell you what version of node you're running, what internal/native modules are loaded (different from NPM modules), and various config settings under `process.config`.

Here's an example, from my AWS Cloud9 instance when emulating a Lambda environment:

```
2020-04-22 22:32:22.590 process {
  version: 'v12.16.1',
  versions: {
    node: '12.16.1',
    v8: '7.8.279.23-node.31',
    uv: '1.34.0',
    zlib: '1.2.11',
    brotli: '1.0.7',
    ares: '1.15.0',
    modules: '72',
    nghttp2: '1.40.0',
    napi: '5',
    llhttp: '2.0.4',
    http_parser: '2.9.3',
    openssl: '1.1.1d',
    cldr: '36.0',
    icu: '65.1',
    tz: '2019c',
    unicode: '12.1'
  },
  arch: 'x64',
  platform: 'linux',
  release: {
    name: 'node',
    lts: 'Erbium',
    sourceUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1.tar.gz',
    headersUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-headers.tar.gz'
  },
  _rawDebug: [Function: _rawDebug],
  moduleLoadList: [
    'Internal Binding native_module',
    'Internal Binding errors',
    'Internal Binding buffer',
    'NativeModule internal/errors',
    'Internal Binding config',
    'Internal Binding constants',
    'Internal Binding util',
    'Internal Binding types',
    'NativeModule internal/util',
    'NativeModule internal/util/types',
    'NativeModule internal/assert',
    'NativeModule internal/util/inspect',
    'NativeModule events',
    'Internal Binding string_decoder',
    'NativeModule internal/validators',
    'NativeModule internal/buffer',
    'Internal Binding icu',
    'NativeModule buffer',
    'NativeModule internal/process/per_thread',
    'Internal Binding process_methods',
    'Internal Binding credentials',
    'Internal Binding async_wrap',
    'Internal Binding task_queue',
    'NativeModule internal/async_hooks',
    'NativeModule internal/process/promises',
    'NativeModule internal/fixed_queue',
    'NativeModule internal/process/task_queues',
    'Internal Binding trace_events',
    'NativeModule internal/console/constructor',
    'NativeModule internal/console/global',
    'NativeModule internal/util/inspector',
    'Internal Binding inspector',
    'NativeModule internal/querystring',
    'NativeModule internal/constants',
    'NativeModule path',
    'Internal Binding url',
    'NativeModule internal/url',
    'NativeModule internal/encoding',
    'Internal Binding timers',
    'NativeModule internal/linkedlist',
    'NativeModule internal/priority_queue',
    'NativeModule internal/util/debuglog',
    'NativeModule internal/timers',
    'NativeModule timers',
    'NativeModule internal/process/execution',
    'NativeModule internal/process/warning',
    'NativeModule internal/process/signal',
    'Internal Binding options',
    'NativeModule internal/options',
    'NativeModule internal/bootstrap/pre_execution',
    'NativeModule internal/inspector_async_hook',
    'Internal Binding fs',
    'NativeModule internal/fs/utils',
    'Internal Binding fs_dir',
    'NativeModule internal/fs/dir',
    'NativeModule fs',
    'NativeModule internal/idna',
    'NativeModule url',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/cjs/helpers',
    'NativeModule internal/source_map/source_map_cache',
    'Internal Binding contextify',
    'NativeModule vm',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/cjs/loader',
    'NativeModule internal/modules/run_main',
    'Internal Binding module_wrap',
    'NativeModule util',
    'NativeModule internal/assert/assertion_error',
    'NativeModule assert',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/pipeline',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/end-of-stream',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/legacy',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/buffer_list',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/destroy',
    'NativeModule internal/streams/state',
    'NativeModule _stream_readable',
    'NativeModule _stream_writable',
    'NativeModule _stream_duplex',
    'NativeModule _stream_transform',
    'NativeModule _stream_passthrough',
    'NativeModule stream',
    'NativeModule internal/net',
    'Internal Binding uv',
    'Internal Binding stream_wrap',
    'Internal Binding tcp_wrap',
    'Internal Binding pipe_wrap',
    'NativeModule internal/stream_base_commons',
    'NativeModule internal/dtrace',
    'NativeModule net',
    'NativeModule _http_agent',
    'Internal Binding http_parser_llhttp',
    'NativeModule internal/freelist',
    'NativeModule _http_incoming',
    'NativeModule _http_common',
    'Internal Binding performance',
    'NativeModule internal/http',
    'NativeModule _http_outgoing',
    'NativeModule _http_client',
    'NativeModule _http_server',
    'NativeModule http'
  ],
  binding: [Function: binding],
  _linkedBinding: [Function: _linkedBinding],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    newListener: [Function: startListeningIfSignal],
    removeListener: [Function: stopListeningIfSignal],
    warning: [Function: onWarning],
    uncaughtException: [Function],
    unhandledRejection: [Function],
    beforeExit: [Function: invoke]
  },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  domain: null,
  _exiting: false,
  config: {
    target_defaults: {
      cflags: [],
      default_configuration: 'Release',
      defines: [],
      include_dirs: [],
      libraries: []
    },
    variables: {
      asan: 0,
      build_v8_with_gn: false,
      coverage: false,
      debug_nghttp2: false,
      enable_lto: false,
      enable_pgo_generate: false,
      enable_pgo_use: false,
      force_dynamic_crt: 0,
      gas_version: '2.29',
      host_arch: 'x64',
      icu_data_in: '../../deps/icu/source/data/in/icudt65l.dat',
      icu_endianness: 'l',
      icu_gyp_path: 'tools/icu/icu-generic.gyp',
      icu_path: 'deps/icu',
      icu_small: false,
      icu_ver_major: '65',
      is_debug: 0,
      llvm_version: '0.0',
      napi_build_version: '5',
      node_byteorder: 'little',
      node_debug_lib: false,
      node_enable_d8: false,
      node_install_npm: true,
      node_module_version: 72,
      node_no_browser_globals: false,
      node_prefix: '/var/lang',
      node_release_urlbase: '',
      node_report: true,
      node_shared: false,
      node_shared_cares: false,
      node_shared_http_parser: false,
      node_shared_libuv: false,
      node_shared_nghttp2: false,
      node_shared_openssl: false,
      node_shared_zlib: false,
      node_tag: '',
      node_target_type: 'executable',
      node_use_bundled_v8: true,
      node_use_dtrace: false,
      node_use_etw: false,
      node_use_large_pages: false,
      node_use_large_pages_script_lld: false,
      node_use_node_code_cache: true,
      node_use_node_snapshot: true,
      node_use_openssl: true,
      node_use_v8_platform: true,
      node_with_ltcg: false,
      node_without_node_options: false,
      openssl_fips: '',
      openssl_is_fips: false,
      shlib_suffix: 'so.72',
      target_arch: 'x64',
      v8_enable_gdbjit: 0,
      v8_enable_i18n_support: 1,
      v8_enable_inspector: 1,
      v8_no_strict_aliasing: 1,
      v8_optimized_debug: 1,
      v8_promise_internal_field_count: 1,
      v8_random_seed: 0,
      v8_trace_maps: 0,
      v8_use_siphash: 1,
      v8_use_snapshot: 1,
      want_separate_host_toolset: 0
    }
  },
  dlopen: [Function: dlopen],
  uptime: [Function: uptime],
  _getActiveRequests: [Function: _getActiveRequests],
  _getActiveHandles: [Function: _getActiveHandles],
  reallyExit: [Function: reallyExit],
  _kill: [Function: _kill],
  hrtime: [Function: hrtime] { bigint: [Function: hrtimeBigInt] },
  cpuUsage: [Function: cpuUsage],
  resourceUsage: [Function: resourceUsage],
  memoryUsage: [Function: memoryUsage],
  kill: [Function: kill],
  exit: [Function: exit],
  openStdin: [Function],
  getuid: [Function: getuid],
  geteuid: [Function: geteuid],
  getgid: [Function: getgid],
  getegid: [Function: getegid],
  getgroups: [Function: getgroups],
  allowedNodeEnvironmentFlags: [Getter/Setter],
  assert: [Function: deprecated],
  features: {
    inspector: true,
    debug: false,
    uv: true,
    ipv6: true,
    tls_alpn: true,
    tls_sni: true,
    tls_ocsp: true,
    tls: true,
    cached_builtins: true
  },
  _fatalException: [Function],
  setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function: setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback],
  hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function: hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback],
  emitWarning: [Function: emitWarning],
  nextTick: [Function: nextTick],
  _tickCallback: [Function: runNextTicks],
  _debugProcess: [Function: _debugProcess],
  _debugEnd: [Function: _debugEnd],
  _startProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function: _startProfilerIdleNotifier],
  _stopProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function: _stopProfilerIdleNotifier],
  stdout: [Getter],
  stdin: [Getter],
  stderr: [Getter],
  abort: [Function: abort],
  umask: [Function: wrappedUmask],
  chdir: [Function: wrappedChdir],
  cwd: [Function: wrappedCwd],
  initgroups: [Function: initgroups],
  setgroups: [Function: setgroups],
  setegid: [Function],
  seteuid: [Function],
  setgid: [Function],
  setuid: [Function],
  env: {
    AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION: '$LATEST',
    HOSTNAME: '164a55144521',
    _LAMBDA_CONTROL_SOCKET: '14',
    AWS_SAM_LOCAL: 'true',
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: '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',
    AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT: '15',
    AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME: '/aws/lambda/test',
    LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT: '/var/task',
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib',
    AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API: '127.0.0.1:9001',
    AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME: '2020/04/22/[$LATEST]8ac4142c629e7e08931e5a0eaff80123',
    _LAMBDA_SHARED_MEM_FD: '11',
    AWS_EXECUTION_ENV: 'AWS_Lambda_nodejs12.x',
    _LAMBDA_RUNTIME_LOAD_TIME: '1530232235231',
    AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME: 'test',
    AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS: '169.254.79.2:2000',
    PATH: '/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin',
    _LAMBDA_LOG_FD: '9',
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1',
    PWD: '/var/task',
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'YNF6WsPQ2sXHi3CNi5a3TDuL2LnGZZdGLHv6x7J1',
    LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR: '/var/runtime',
    LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
    NODE_PATH: '/opt/nodejs/node12/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task',
    TZ: ':UTC',
    AWS_REGION: 'us-east-1',
    AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_HANDLER: 'RunSync/index.handler',
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'ASIA4WQEVF3YKL2RO2HZ',
    SHLVL: '0',
    HOME: '/home/sbx_user1051',
    _AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS: '169.254.79.2',
    _AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_PORT: '2000',
    _X_AMZN_TRACE_ID: 'Root=1-dc99d00f-c079a84d433534434534ef0d;Parent=91ed514f1e5c03b2;Sampled=1',
    _LAMBDA_SB_ID: '7',
    AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING: 'LOG_ERROR',
    _LAMBDA_CONSOLE_SOCKET: '16',
    _HANDLER: 'RunSync/index.handler',
    AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE: '256',
    AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY: '{}'
  },
  title: '/var/lang/bin/node',
  argv: [ '/var/lang/bin/node', '/var/runtime/index.js' ],
  execArgv: [
    '--expose-gc',
    '--max-http-header-size',
    '81920',
    '--max-semi-space-size=12',
    '--max-old-space-size=231'
  ],
  pid: 12,
  ppid: 1,
  execPath: '/var/lang/bin/node',
  debugPort: 9229,
  argv0: '/var/lang/bin/node',
  _preload_modules: [],
  mainModule: Module {
    id: '.',
    path: '/var/runtime',
    exports: {},
    parent: null,
    filename: '/var/runtime/index.js',
    loaded: true,
    children: [ [Module], [Module], [Module], [Module], [Module], [Module] ],
    paths: [
      '/var/runtime/node_modules',
      '/var/node_modules',
      '/node_modules'
    ]
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```